# Ruby on Rails: How to populate an array using a form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

[noob disclaimer] So I'm beginning with rails and I'm trying to have a form that adds toppings to a food order.
How can I make a form that for each checkbox 'ticked' the submission will add that topping to the array of ordered toppings to that food?

Answer (score 0):

You're asking rather a lot so I think a couple of awesome railscasts are in order.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2

Comment: It also seems to be at bit similar to the not-less-awesome http://railscasts.com/episodes/17-habtm-checkboxes